# Greatest common divisor of an integer 'a' and its sum with 2.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I need to prove that the $\gcd(a, a+2)$ equals either 1 or 2.  Intuitively this makes sense to me.  If a is an odd integer then the gcd is 1, if a is even, the gcd is 2.  I'm having trouble writing a logical proof of this, however.

I would guess that a has some prime factorization $a = p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$.  Then $a+2 = p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_k^{e_k} + 2$.  If a is even, then that first prime (assuming ordering) is $p_1 = 2$.  We can factor out a 2 from $a+2$ as $a+2 = 2(p_1^{e_1 - 1} \cdots p_k^{e_k} + 1)$.  Clearly both a and a+2 would be even numbers with gcd = 2$.  If a is odd, then we cannot factor out a 2 here.

Am I on the right track with this?

Comment: You may use $\gcd(x,y) = \gcd(x, y-x)$

Answer (score 2):

$k|a,k|b\Rightarrow k|ax+by$ for all $x,y$. This follows immediately from the definitions. So if $k|a,k|a+2$, then $k|2$

Answer (score 1):

Proof:

- $a=1\implies\gcd(a+2,a)=\gcd(3,1)=1$
- $a=2\implies\gcd(a+2,a)=\gcd(4,2)=2$
- $a>2\implies\gcd(a+2,a)=\gcd(a,a+2-a)=\gcd(a,2)\leq2$

Answer (score 0):

let $d = \gcd(a, a+2)$
$ \implies   d | a$ and  $d|(a+2) $
$\implies  d|(a+2)-a$

which is same as $d|2$